# Entity Framework 7 Migration Scaffolding in Class Library with Configuration

Tags: entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-core, dnx

Trying to add migrations to an EF7 Model that lives in an ASP.NET 5 class library. When running `dnx . ef migration add mymigration` fails with different results depending on which project I run it on.

If I run it in the folder of the main project, it cannot locate a `DbContext`, this makes sense because the `DbContext` is in the shared project and ef commands likely don't care about dependencies.

If I run it in the folder of the shared project, it does not have access to the connection string specified in the startup.cs. I have gleaned from questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786505/cannot-run-migration-on-entity-framework-7-beta4-in-class-library-package) that it does work from the shared project if you specify the connection string in the `OnConfiguring` method of the `DbContext` but I really would like to keep this code separate from the configuration.

I came across some [issue logs](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/823) in the EF7 repository that mention they implemented command line options for specifying a project and a context but there are no examples and I couldn't figure out how to use it from looking at the source code in the commit history.

Comment: Where are you storing your connection string? Is it hard coded into Startup.cs?

Comment: It is in config.json and loaded with Configuration into AddDbContext<T>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an approach that might work for you.

> If I run it in the folder of the shared project, it does not have access to the connection string specified in the startup.cs.

## Startup.cs

I'm assuming that in your Startup.cs, you're specifying the connection string by accessing `Configuration` rather than by hard coding it. Further, I'm assuming that in your Startup.cs file's constructor, you're setting up configuration from a few sources. In other words, your Startup.cs might look something like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Config { get; set; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var config = new Configuration()
            .AddJsonFile("config.json")
            .AddUserSecrets()
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Config = config;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Config["ConnectionStrings:MyDbContext"]);
            });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var db = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
        db.Database.AsSqlServer().EnsureCreated();

        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });
    }
}
```

## config.json

Further, I'm assuming that you're adding the connection string to a config.json in the root of your project (or that you adding it via user secrets or environmental variables.) Your config.json might look something like this:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDbContext": "Some-Connection-String"
  }
}
```

If you're not doing it that way, it might be worth trying it.

> I have gleaned from questions like this that it does work from the shared project if you specify the connection string in the OnConfiguring method of the DbContext but I really would like to keep this code separate from the configuration.

## DbContext

If my assumptions above are correct, then you can access the connection string in the `DbContext` by using the same pattern that you used in the `Startup` class. That is, in the `DbContext` constructor, setup the `IConfiguration`. Then, in `OnConfiguring`, access the connection string. It might look something like this:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<SomeModel>().Key(e => e.Id);
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var connString = Config["ConnectionStrings:MyDbContext"];
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connString);
    }

    public IConfiguration Config { get; set; }

    public MyDbContext()
    {
        var config = new Configuration()
            .AddJsonFile("config.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Config = config;
    }
}
```

## Project Structure

You'll of course need to have a config.json file in the root of your shared projects folder too. So, your projects' structure could look something like this:

```
SharedDataContext
    Migrations
    config.json
    project.json

WebApp
    config.json
    project.json
    Startup.cs
```

In the above, both config.json files contain a connection string setting for the `DbContext`.

## Some Thoughts

If you don't like duplicating the config.json connection string stuff, then you can use environmental variables or user secrets instead.

Comment: This is a much more acceptable workaround than moving the entire namespace into the main project. Migration add worked perfect, hit a bump with apply: Since I was using a custom `DataDirectory` I had to do some context detection. When run from the command line `Path.GetFullPath("..\\MainProject")` gives me "C:\Path\To\My\Project\src\MainProject", but when running the actual project I get "C:\Program Files (x86)\MainProject" instead! So I added a check to see if the path contains the text "src" and it works now. This should also port to production since environment vars will overwrite it all.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer until something less hacky comes along.

Comment: @CuddleBunny I'm glad it worked out and am looking forward to seeing something less hacky. Maybe someone from the EF team will contribute an answer.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin with beta5 they changed the Config interface to require a base path, which I would usually get from IApplicationEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath.  The problem is that when I add IApplicationEnvironment to the constructor, I get an error that there is no default constructor when I run "ef migration add".  I wonder if it would be so bad to hardcode the path or the connection string.  This all is very hacky and unfortunate though :(  Who would put their context in the same project as web?  Why such an oversight?

Comment: @RyanLangton for the BasePath value you can use relative path syntax @".\"; `var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder(@".\", null);` or @"..\MyStartupProject\" for example.